# Problem with map.root

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When i set map.root :controller => "welcome", I get the standard rails page, rather than the welcome page.  I have deleted public/index.html and "localhost:3000/welcome" works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running in development mode? Try restarting the development server and pressing Ctrl + F5 in your web browser to force a page reload.

Comment: Ah that worked!  Thanks.  I guess the old page was getting cached.